# Invalid Docker Sock

Tags: docker, airflow

I've set up airflow in a docker container on Mac OS according to their documentation [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html#fetching-docker-compose-yaml).  In a separate container, I've spun up a python instance so I can run dbt models.

I'd like to use `DockerOperator` in airflow to run dbt models.  To do so, I've added

```
 volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

To all airflow services and have created the following DAG

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.operators.docker_operator import DockerOperator



default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'start_date': datetime(2024, 1, 1),
}

dag = DAG('dbt_run_dag',
         default_args=default_args,
         description='Run dbt run',
         schedule_interval='* */1 * * *',
         catchup=False,
         tags=['dbt-run'])
        
# Define the DockerOperator task
dbt_run_task = DockerOperator(
    task_id='dbt_run',
    image='dbt-dummy',  # Use the same image as in your docker-compose
    api_version='auto',
    auto_remove=True,
    command='cd /root/dbt/sandbox && dbt run',
    docker_url='/var/run/docker.sock',  # Assumes Docker Daemon is available at this URL
    network_mode='sandbox_default',  # Specify your Docker network here if needed
    dag=dag,
)

# Set the order of the tasks in the DAG
dbt_run_task
```

The DAG fails, raising this in the logs

```
raise errors.DockerException(
docker.errors.DockerException: Invalid bind address format: /var/run/docker.sock)
```

Can someone help me understand:

- What is a bind address, and
- How to fix the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [DockerOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-docker/stable/_api/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker/index.html#airflow.providers.docker.operators.docker.DockerOperator) in Airflow docs. It's default value of `docker_url` parameter is `unix://var/run/docker.sock`. Since this is exactly what you are using you can skip the parameter or - if you want to be explicit - you're just missing the `unix:/` prefix.

Bind address is the address Docker daemon is listening on. See [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/) for more info about this.

> **Bind Docker to another host/port or a Unix socket**
>
> With -H it is possible to make the Docker daemon to listen on a
> specific IP and port. By default, it will listen on
> unix:///var/run/docker.sock to allow only local connections by the
> root user. [...]
>
> -H accepts host and port assignment in the following format:
>
> tcp://[host]:[port][path] or unix://path